# NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Long.hashCode

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have the following override of method on `hashCode` in `AbstractORM` class:

```
var _id = Random().nextLong()

override fun getId() = _id // AbstractORM class implements an interface that defines this method getId()

override fun hashCode() = getId().hashCode()
```

which suddenly started to throw the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Long.hashCode
   at com.company.ormlite.AbstractORM.hashCode(AbstractORM.kt:271)
   at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:390)
   at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:95)
   at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.toCollection(_Arrays.kt:6518)
   at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.toSet(_Arrays.kt:6853)
   at kotlin.collections.SetsKt__SetsKt.setOf(Sets.kt:32)
   at com.company.android.tna.orm.DataManager.getTables(DataManager.kt:16)
   at com.company.android.tna.orm.DataManager.getTables(DataManager.kt:10)
   at com.company.android.core.utils.AbstractDataManager.create(AbstractDataManager.kt:25)
   at com.company.android.core.utils.AbstractDataManager.start(AbstractDataManager.kt:44)
   at com.company.android.core.utils.AbstractZKApplication.onCreate(AbstractZKApplication.kt:54)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This has me dumbfounded for several reasons:

- All classes in Java and Kotlin have `hashCode` method since it is inherited from `Object` or `Any`.
- How can it not find a method that is on the Android SDK itself? If the SDK is not present, how is it running at all?
- When inspecting that line of code in IntelliJ IDEA, it sends me to `kotlin.Any.hashCode`, not to `java.lang.Long.hashcode`.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post signature of `getId()` method along with imports?

Comment: @chandil03 I've added requested information. There are no imports relevant to these methods. All imports are from internal libraries for ORM and java.util. We have no other implementation of `Long`.

Comment: I used your three lines, it is working fine. I did not override getId as i did not know which interface you are using. If you let me know the interface that you are implementing then i might be able to help.

Comment: @chandil03 Yeah it worked fine for me until yesterday, so it must be definitely something in my build messing it. I don't think the interface is related at all. It's just a simple interface with that method getId(), nothing more.

Comment: Also upgrading kotlin from 1.3.20 to 1.3.30 causes this issue. See [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31027).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After checking the compiled `AbstractORM` class I found the problem: newer Kotlin versions generate a different code for that line

```
getId().hashCode()
```

Kotlin 1.1.2 generates the following code:

```
Long.valueOf(this.getId()).hashCode()
```

while newer versions of Kotlin generate this other code:

```
Long.hashCode(this.getId())
```

The problem is that this static method `Long.hashCode(long)` in Android is only available since API 24 (Android 7.0), while I'm testing on an Android device that has version 4.1 (API 16).

<strike>I'm temporarily fixing by calculating the hash code manually although I've opened an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19968).</strike>

```
override fun hashCode() = (getId() xor getId().ushr(32)).toInt()
```

As commented on the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19968), switching to Java 1.6 target for the Kotlin compiler generates the old compatible code.

[image]

PS: I'm not 100% sure about those Kotlin versions, please take with a grain of salt.

Comment: Be careful if you override such settings into your build.gradle file: `compileKotlin { kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.6" } }`

Comment: @m0skit0 
I am facing the same issue and I don't want to downgrade to JVM 1.6. Can you tell how to fix this issue for JVM 1.8 and API level less than 24

Comment: @AbdulRehmanYawarKhan I'm same as you, using JVM 1.8 and API < 24, did you read answer?

Comment: @StéphanePéchard I'm in love with you.

Comment: How is this not more of an issue for people? I ,like @AbdulRehmanYawarKhan, do not want to downgrade to 1.6 if it can be helped.

Comment: @StuStirling It's pretty simple: you can't use target 1.8 if your min SDK is less than 24. Devices with API < 24 do not support 1.8 features.

Answer (score 5):

Overriding the `hashCode()` function, as m0skit0 suggested, worked for me. I implemented this:

```
override fun hashCode() : Int = id.toString().hashCode()
```

My Kotlin compiler setting in AndroidStudio is :

- incremental compilation enabled
- target JVM ver. 1.6

Comment: much better solution from just dropping support to old APIs

Comment: If you have Kotlin to compile to 1.6 you don't need this.

Comment: @Ahmedna What do you mean "just dropping support to old APIs"?

Comment: @m0skit0 with kotlin v 1.3.30 launched last week , while having 1.6 any device with api < 24 this error is thrown  , grater APIs are working fine  

So i just need to avoid using these methods

Comment: @Ahmedna Did you read my answer? You just have to set the Kotlin compiler to generate 1.6 compatible code. Doesn't matter which API or Kotlin version.

Comment: @m0skit0 I've set complier to 1.6 everything was good until last week , I updated to kotlin 1.3.30 , all users with api < 24 started to crashed , I debugged with 1.6 and older version of kotlin all api were working , then with kotlin 1.3.30 all APIs pre 24 crashed

Comment: Targetting JVM to v1.6 is not mandatory. Anyway, thank you, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about how to solve your problem, but I'll try to explain why are you getting this exception.

In **Java 8** a new *[static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode-long-)* was added to a `Long` class:

```
public static int hashCode(long value)
```

And since then `hashCode()` method looks like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return hashCode(this.value); // call Long.hashCode() static method
}
```

So it seems that you have some issues with **Java** version.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this explains anything about my error.

Comment: Most probably you're trying to run Java 8 compiled code on JVM that does not support 1.8 features.

Comment: Definitely not, this is Android and it is always set to Java 6. In any case I checked again the Java version target and it is 6. Also I'm not calling that new static method, note it has a parameter.

Comment: But it is definitely something broken in my build, some Kotlin versions or something, thanks for putting me on that way!

Comment: @m0skit0 may be your java 6 is having this issue as it is too old. try switching to 7 or 8.

Comment: Android is Java 6 only :)

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and the solution for me is to assign both `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions` in build.gradle to version **1.8**

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  // For Kotlin projects
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

Referenced from [Use Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) of Android Developers official website.

Comment: If  you want to upgrade to Java 8, yes, this is valid solution.