# Why should I switch to jvmTarget 1.8 with my kotlin project and how is it savely possible?

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

Today we had a serious issue with our jvmTarget 1.8 being implemented differently in Android API 24 than below, and a change in a server reply triggered thousands of crashes. The suggested solution was to downgrade the jvmTarget to 1.6. I'm freaking out a bit that this happened at all and I have no clue how I can write a unit test that would have detected the issue but on the other hand I don't know why I should not just switch to jvmTarget 1.6. But what's the deal? Performance? Features? Coroutines seam to work regardless and I couldn't find why pick one or the other. Only how.

Comment: I suppose you read through [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)? You probably implemented some java-8 only methods, lowering target to 1.7 should be enough though.

Comment: No. The issue was kotlin related as far as I understood [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45939508/969478). What you describe should result in compile time issues not runtime errors like this:

 `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method hashCode(I)I in class Ljava/lang/Integer; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Integer' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar`