# How to use Kotlin with Butterknife 10.1.0 on minsdk <24?

Tags: android, kotlin, java-8, butterknife

I am migrating my Android project to AndroidX libraries. Butterknife 10.x has improved support for it, so i think it is good to use that. My project is made in Kotlin (1.3.30).

Butterknife versions >8 require that you use Java 8 like this:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

This works great for minsdk >=24. And for a good part it works with lower versions too. But as Kotlin compiles to Java 8 some features dont work on minsdk <24. Such as the one that i am getting the following exception for.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method hashCode(J)I in class Ljava/lang/Long; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Long' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Long.hashCode() is a new api in Java 8, but not supported in older android versions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935788/nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-long-hashcode) question solves the same problem by telling the compiler to use Java 6, but that is unsupported with butterknife 10.x which i need for AndroidX.

I suppose this is quite a common issue, but i have not found a solution for it. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with using Kotlin 1.3.30 (see [This issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31027)). I have temporarily fixed the issue by using Kotlin 1.3.21. In a future version of D8 also the static methods of Long and Char will be desugared [Issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129730297). It is already fixed but it will take a bit of time before it hits the stable release of D8. After that this will not be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need Butterknife when you have [Kotlin android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).
Using it is much more simple.

Like this:

```
myTextView.text = "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I know that this is not needed, but i like the syntax of Butterknife more as i dont like the global namespace of all those things. Also this is not recommeded by google anymore. If there is no other solution i will do this, but i prefer to use Butterknife.

Comment: you may try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45939508/7331042) and also check comments there, maybe it will help

Comment: I already read that answer and tried `compileKotlin { kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.6" } }`. That doesnt work