# Switch to Kotlin 1.3.30 breaks hashCode only on Android API 21

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I switched over my Android project from 1.3.20 to 1.3.30 and I am suddenly getting following exceptions from some of the classes when they call hashCode() method. Note, I am getting this exception only on Android platform API 21 & 22, beyond Android API 24, everything works fine.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method hashCode(J)I
>   in class Ljava/lang/Long; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'java.lang.Long' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

There is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935788/nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-long-hashcode/45939508#45939508) that mentions similar symptoms but that was for Kotlin 1.2, I am wondering if anybody is encountering similar situation and if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you may set a JVM target for Kotlin compilation to `"1.6"`, as Kotlin 1.3.30 has started to infer the JVM target from the Java version in `android.compileOptions` and chooses `"1.8"` if both `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` are set to that or higher.

In the module's `build.gradle`, add:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.6'
    }
}
```

There will be no need to do this once [the issue in D8 desugaring](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129730297) is fixed.

This issue is tracked in the Kotlin issue tracker as [KT-31027](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31027).

Comment: Would love to understand the implications of changing `jvmTarget`...

Answer (score 1):

This is related to this issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129730297 so solution seems to be to upgrade to latest AGP!